# Issue in canvas view saving mode using SPenSdk libraries

Tags: java, android

I have created an app in which I have used SPenSdk libraries, My app is simple, What I do is on the start of the app I open a `canvasView` with a pen, eraser, undo and redo option.

I have two buttons, one save the canvas as an image in my SD card and another button is used to load the saved images.

Now my issue is, whenever I load the saved image and edit the saved images and again save the images, it is saved as new images instead of updating the saved images, why it happens?

I put my code here. Help me to solve this out, if possible with an example.

**Code For java File**

```
public class CanvasActivity extends Activity {
         
private CanvasView  m_CanvasView;
private SettingView m_SettingView;
private Button      m_PenButton, m_EraserButton, m_UndoButton, m_RedoButton, m_SaveButton;      
private int         mButtonTextNormalColor;

public static final String DEFAULT_APP_IMAGEDATA_DIRECTORY = "/mnt/sdcard/SmemoExample";

private File        m_Folder = null;
public static final String SAVED_FILE_EXTENSION = "png";
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH = "path";
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_NAME = "filename";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    m_PenButton     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pen_button);
    m_PenButton.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    mButtonTextNormalColor = m_PenButton.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
    
    m_EraserButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.erase_button);
    m_EraserButton.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    
    m_UndoButton    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
    m_UndoButton.setOnClickListener(undoNredoBtnClickListener);
    m_UndoButton.setEnabled(false);
    
    m_RedoButton    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redo_button);
    m_RedoButton.setOnClickListener(undoNredoBtnClickListener);       
    m_RedoButton.setEnabled(false);
    
    m_SaveButton    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    m_SaveButton.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    
    m_CanvasView    = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvas_view);
    m_SettingView   = (SettingView) findViewById(R.id.setting_view);

    m_CanvasView.setSettingView(m_SettingView);
    m_CanvasView.setOnHistoryChangeListener(historyChangeListener);
    m_CanvasView.setInitializeFinishListener(mInitializeFinishListener);
    
    m_Folder        = new File(DEFAULT_APP_IMAGEDATA_DIRECTORY);
    
    String mFileName = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_NAME);        
    loadCanvas(mFileName);
}

private OnClickListener undoNredoBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == m_UndoButton) {
            m_CanvasView.undo();
        } else if (v == m_RedoButton) {
            m_CanvasView.redo();
        }

        m_UndoButton.setEnabled(m_CanvasView.isUndoable());
        m_RedoButton.setEnabled(m_CanvasView.isRedoable());
    }
};

OnClickListener mBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == m_PenButton.getId()) {
            m_CanvasView.changeModeTo(CanvasView.PEN_MODE);
            m_PenButton.setSelected(true);
            m_PenButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            m_EraserButton.setSelected(false);
            m_EraserButton.setTextColor(mButtonTextNormalColor);
            
            if (m_PenButton.isSelected()) {
                m_SettingView.showView(AbstractSettingView.PEN_SETTING_VIEW);

            }
        } else if (v.getId() == m_EraserButton.getId()) {
            m_CanvasView.changeModeTo(CanvasView.ERASER_MODE);

            m_EraserButton.setSelected(true);
            m_EraserButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            m_PenButton.setSelected(false);
            m_PenButton.setTextColor(mButtonTextNormalColor);
            
            if (m_EraserButton.isSelected()) {
                m_SettingView.showView(AbstractSettingView.ERASER_SETTING_VIEW);
            }
        } else if(v.getId() == m_SaveButton.getId()) {
            saveCanvas();
        }
    }
};

public boolean saveCanvas() {
    byte[] buffer = m_CanvasView.getData();

    if (buffer == null)
        return false;
    if (!(m_Folder.exists()))
        m_Folder.mkdirs();
    
    String savePath = m_Folder.getPath() + '/' + UtilitiesActivity.getUniqueFilename(m_Folder, "image", SAVED_FILE_EXTENSION);

    if (UtilitiesActivity.writeBytedata(savePath, buffer))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public boolean loadCanvas(String fileName) {
    String loadPath = m_Folder.getPath() + '/' + fileName;
   
    byte[] buffer = UtilitiesActivity.readBytedata(loadPath);

    if (buffer == null)
        return false;

    m_CanvasView.setData(buffer);

    return true;
}

private CanvasView.OnHistoryChangeListener historyChangeListener = new CanvasView.OnHistoryChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHistoryChanged(boolean bUndoable, boolean bRedoable) {
        m_UndoButton.setEnabled(bUndoable);
        m_RedoButton.setEnabled(bRedoable);
    }
};

CanvasView.InitializeFinishListener mInitializeFinishListener = new CanvasView.InitializeFinishListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.canvas_bg);
        m_CanvasView.setBackgroundImage(bg);
        bg.recycle();
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you save an image, it takes a new name and save that. Old image wont be overwritten. So you can edit the save canvas function. The method shown below

```
public boolean saveCanvas()
{
byte[] buffer = mCanvasView.getData();

if(buffer == null)
        return false;

    String savePath = mFolder.getPath() + '/' + ExampleUtils.getUniqueFilename(mFolder, "image", SAVED_FILE_EXTENSION);
    Log.d(TAG, "Save Path = " + savePath);

    if(ExampleUtils.writeBytedata(savePath, buffer))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;       
}
```

function "getUniqueFilename" generates a new name.So if you update an image, just avoid the function

```
ExampleUtils.getUniqueFilename(mFolder, "image", SAVED_FILE_EXTENSION);
```

and save with old name. Then it will be overwritten.

Comment: When you load an image, save the file name temporarily from loadCanvas() function. Set a flag that shows the canvas is loaded or new. While saving, check the flag and if it is loaded save the image with the old name. Otherwise generate unique name

Comment: can u tell me one thing...now i am saving my images in sd card..so when there is no sd card in the device then my app crash..so its there other way to save the images in such a way that i will be part of my app...if any example u have plz share me..

Comment: @Anshuman: The written pat is to sdcard. U can change the path in the code itself

Comment: But where should i stored the images..can it be stored in my app only..is there a way to do it..